# C program immediately exits after run?

Tags: c

Hey I have a real quick question about a program I've written. For some reason it's exiting immediately after it runs. There are no errors when I hit run, but something's obviously wrong.

Because I can't get it to run at all, I can't test it to make sure it's doing exactly what I need it to.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXCHARS 31

struct TempInfo
    {
        char city[MAXCHARS];
        int day;
        double fahr;
        double cels;
    };

void input_TempInfo(struct TempInfo * arr, int size);
void print_TempInfo(struct TempInfo * arr, int size);

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int size;
    struct TempInfo arr[size];
    struct TempInfo * arrPtr;
    arrPtr = arr;

    do
    {
        printf("How many cities / days / temps would you like to enter? ");
        scanf("%i", &size);
        if (size < 1 || size > 20)
        {
            printf("Not a valid number. Type another: ");
            scanf("%i", &size);
        }
    } while (size >= 1 && size <= 20);

    input_TempInfo(arrPtr, size);
    print_TempInfo(arrPtr, size);

    return 0;
}

void input_TempInfo(struct TempInfo * arr, int size)
{
    int i, k;

    for (i = 0, k = 0; k < size; i++, k++)
    {
        printf("Enter the city: ");
        while (((arr[k].city[i] = getchar()) != '\n') && (i < MAXCHARS))
            i++;
        arr[k].city[i] = '\0';

        do
        {
            printf("Enter the day: ");
            scanf("%i", &arr[k].day);
            if (arr[k].day < 1 || arr[k].day > 366)
            {
                printf("Invalid day number. Type another: ");
                scanf("%i", &arr[k].day);
            }
        } while (arr[k].day >= 1 && arr[k].day <= 366);

        printf("Enter a temperature in Fahrenheit: ");
        scanf("%lf", &arr[k].fahr);

        arr[k].cels = (arr[k].fahr - 32) * 5/9;
    }
}

void print_TempInfo(struct TempInfo * arr, int size)
{
    int i, k;

    for (i = 0, k = 0; k < size; i++, k++)
    {
        printf("City\tDay\tFahr\tCels");
        printf("------------------------------");
        printf("%s\t%i\t%.1lf\t%.1lf",
            arr[k].city, arr[k].day, arr[k].fahr, arr[k].cels);
    }
}
```

*EDIT* I rearranged my declarations of my 'arr[size]' and '* arrPtr' to be after the 'do while' And it worked better. Thank you guys so much.

Comment: `int size; struct TempInfo arr[size];` <-- `size` is uninitialized.

Comment: Does it compile.. how do you compile and run it

Comment: How you can know that it is exiting after it run, if you say you can't get it to run?

Comment: `main` should return `int`.

Comment: If you are using visual studio and you can see your project building sucessfully, Try and use CTRL+F5 to run it. It will run with debugging mode and ask you to "Press any key to continue" after the programme is run. If you are using eclipse, you should simply see the output in the console regardless. You haven't given us information whether this compiles or not.

Comment: `} while (size >= 1 && size <= 20);` --> `} while (size < 1 || size > 20);`

Comment: When you ask questions, consider paring down your code to be more 'minimal' in the ["Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It's not entirely the case that you can't debug a program when it quits mysteriously--you can comment out code step by step until you have a program containing only `printf("How many cities / days / temps would you like to enter? ");`.  If that doesn't run, you like have some installation problem with your compiler, but *even still* try `printf("H");`  Process of elimination can help you focus on exactly what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 7):

This code chunk

```
int size;
struct TempInfo arr[size];
struct TempInfo * arrPtr;
arrPtr = arr;
```

is wrong: you are using a [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (variable length array, here `arr`) of uninitialized `size`

I was hoping that if you compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) you would have been warned. Unfortunately, that is not the case (with GCC 4.9), unless you also ask for optimization (so with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O -g` I am getting a warning). so please submit a bug on [GCC bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla)

At least, move the `do` ... `while(size >= 1 && size <= 20);` loop *before* that chunk. Read the documentation of every function you are using. Notice that [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) is returning the count of successfully scanned items, and you should test it!

BTW, you should learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -g run.c -o run` (gcc 4.8.2) does not warn about the uninitialized size ... nevertheless, good advice to always use strict warning levels enabled

Comment: Thanks. So I improved my answer.

Comment: Interesting that enabling optimization changes the warnings - with gcc 4.8.2, I am still not getting warned about `size`, but it prints a bunch of additional warnings ...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I did move the 'do while' and it worked. But I was wondering how I would go about learning how to read the debugger? It has a lot of hexadecimals and octadecimals that I don't know what they mean.

Comment: @JordanLindsay: I am sure that your debugger has some documentation. If your system has no usable debugger, consider changing to some other system; on Linux (which is free software) the `gcc` compiler and the `gdb` debugger have a documentation and many tutorials. So perhaps consider switching to Linux on your PC!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks I'll definitely think about that. I'm using Dev-C only because that's what my teacher told us to use....

Comment: You should consider using a real compiler and a real OS for your development. Once your program is running (e.g. on Linux), porting it to Dev-C would be very easy.